# Asp Net UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net

Estou estudando AspNet e não consigo utilizar o UpdatePanel de forma nenhuma, tenho um webform em uma masterpage aninhada este é o código:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/NestedMasterPage8Form.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Dashboard.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

    <ContentTemplate>

       <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    </ContentTemplate>

    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Este é o código teste do evento click:

```
Label3.Text = "Aspx";
```

Já tentei de varias formas com o botão dentro do ContentTemplate sem indicar a Triggers mas mesmos assim a pagina inteira  atualiza ao clicar no botão, podem me dar uma luz quanto a utilização do UpdatePanel ?

Comment: olá Jorge, sugiro dar uma olhada nesse exemplo que pode te ajudar [Trabalhando com UpdatePanel](https://imasters.com.br/dotnet/trabalhando-com-updatepanel-no-asp-net). Agora uma dica: essa tecnologia é bem ultrapassada, hoje usamos basicamente uma chamada `ajax` e atualizamos o que for preciso na página, se for apenas para estudo, sugiro estudar uma tecnologia mais moderna

Comment: obrigado pela dica vou dar uma pesquisada sobre as técnicas mais atuais.

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso, faltou configurar a condição de atualização do atributo `UpdateMode` para `conditional` e `ChildrenAsTriggers="false"`:

`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional"  ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server">`

Veja que ao configurar `ChildrenAsTriggers` como false, o seu programa fará o controle manual dos gatilhos através da tag `triggers`